# Getting SUM of 2 Values (1 being in SubQuery) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I am at my wits end with this (what should be simple) issue. I figured I had already done all the hardwork (as this MySQL SELECT statement is reasonably complicated IMHO (for me anyway).

I am trying to get the SUM value of two key numeric fields from a MySQL SELECT Statement. I have tried obvious variations, however I cannot make the field value "Regs" from the Subquery available to the parent query to do something like... SUM(Regs+Held) AS Total. Please, Please, Help!

Here is my SQL Code...

```
    SELECT 
        p.product_id AS ID,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(p.cdate, '%c/%e/%y') AS CDate,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(p.mdate, '%c/%e/%y') AS MDate,
        p.product_sku AS SKU,
        s.mf_category_city AS Town,
        s.mf_category_county AS County,
        s.mf_category_state AS State,
        org.mf_name AS Org,
        s.mf_category_name AS Site,
        p.product_name AS ClassName,
        DATE_FORMAT(p.startDate, '%a %m-%d-%Y') AS StartDate,
        DATE_FORMAT(p.endDate, '%a %m-%d-%Y') AS EndDate,
        DATE_FORMAT(p.startTime, '%l:%i %p') AS StartTime,
        DATE_FORMAT(p.endTime, '%l:%i %p') AS EndTime,
        p.age_from,
        p.age_to,
        pr.product_price AS Price,
        CASE 
            WHEN p.class_status = 0 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN p.class_status = 1 THEN 'C' 
            WHEN p.class_status = 2 THEN 'S'
        END AS Status,
        p.product_publish AS Published,
        p.precode AS Code,
        CASE 
            WHEN p.product_refered = 'N' THEN 'USG' 
            WHEN p.product_refered = 'Y' THEN 'REC' 
            WHEN p.product_refered = 'B' THEN 'BOTH'
        END AS REC,
        p.class_target AS Target,
        (SELECT SUM(oi.product_quantity) FROM (jos_sport_childs_xrf AS scx) 
        LEFT JOIN jos_vm_order_item AS oi ON scx.product_id = oi.product_id 
        WHERE scx.product_id = p.product_id AND oi.order_status IN ('C','P')     
        GROUP BY scx.child_id LIMIT 1) AS Regs,
        p.class_held AS Held,
        p.total_registrations AS Total,
        p.site_usage_fee AS Fee,
        p.player_usage_fee AS PlayerFee,
        p.player_usage_percent AS PlayerPercentage,
        u.name AS RD,
        p.product_desc AS Notes,
        CASE 
            WHEN cxref.category_parent_id = 42 THEN 'USSI'
            WHEN cxref.category_parent_id = 98 THEN 'USSI' 
        END AS Company,
        p.belongs_to AS BelongsTo,
        p.missdate1 AS Missdate1,
        p.missdate2 AS Missdate2,
        p.missdate3 AS Missdate3
    FROM (jos_vm_product AS p)
    INNER JOIN jos_vm_manufacturer_category AS s ON p.venue = s.mf_category_id
    LEFT JOIN jos_vm_product_price AS pr ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN jos_users AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN jos_vm_product_category_xref AS x ON p.product_id = x.product_id
    INNER JOIN jos_vm_category_xref AS cxref ON x.category_id = cxref.category_child_id
    LEFT JOIN jos_vm_manufacturer AS org ON s.mf_category_org = org.manufacturer_id
    WHERE p.startDate BETWEEN '2015-03-02' AND '2015-06-14' 
    AND x.category_id IN (102,120,99,106,104,94,59,84,105) 
    AND u.id NOT IN (33731,46660)
```

Held has a simple numerical value and the SubQuery returns a SUM total value of records.

Comment: What does `LIMIT 1` do? And why are you using an OUTER JOIN in the subquery?

Comment: Also, note that it's generally a bad idea to store date and time separately

Comment: FWIW, I tend to avoid correlated subqueries. Instead you can JOIN it as an uncorrelated one by including  scx.child_id in the subquery's SELECT clause, and then joining on that. Don't know if that helps you much, but I think it might.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far... Th MySQL does appear over complex however this has been necessary. The Data structure for this project has always been complex.

The LIMIT 1 was necessary as we had trouble getting the correct SUM value in "Regs" without. I know this suggests another issue, and I will look into refining the SQL at a later date, but for now this is all I have to work with as it has been a live system of 7 years know.

I would also like to avoid correlated sub-queries, however at the moment I do not see a clear way out (given the short time I have to resolve).

Comment: I will test without the "LIMIT 1" to remind myself what the issue was.

Comment: so you have your  `AS Regs` field and `AS Held` and you want to redefine your `AS Total` ? that holds `p.total_registrations` so far?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking to do - Alex

Comment: See below regarding the test (without LIMIT) in the reply to the Answer from - Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the subquery in isolation, and without the correlating reference, so...

```
SELECT SUM(oi.product_quantity) 
     , scx.product_id
  FROM jos_sport_childs_xrf scx
  JOIN jos_vm_order_item oi 
    ON scx.product_id = oi.product_id 
 WHERE oi.order_status IN ('C','P')     
 GROUP 
    BY scx.child_id;
```

Here we `SELECT` product_id (we do this because we know we're going to need it later), but we `GROUP BY` child_id. This is bad. What should we do instead?

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment I removed the LIMIT 1 to remind myself of the previous error in the Subquery...

[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

So I know there is something not quite with the Subquery, however with LIMIT 1 it DOES return the correct value AS "Regs" which is visible in the output. However just cannot get a total value of Regs + Held = ???

Comment: If it returns the correct answer, it does so by luck! That approach should not be relied upon.

Comment: I still have no idea on the Subquery what the problem is? I can correctly calculate the totals for over 3,500 records with that Subquery. I just can't add the returned value to the "Held" integar for a Total.

Comment: As I've tried to explain, you select one thing, but group by another. You claim that this gives the correct answer but unless both child_id and product_id are unique, this seems to me to be nonsensical.